# Transforming object recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object, or an array of objects, with props containing strings, arrays and other objects.

I want to transform the nested arrays containing objects with the prop language into an object with the language as key and the object itself as prop.

Lets say I want to transform recursively this object:

```
{
    "WhatPage": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "WhatPageTranslations": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "What",
                    "WhatPageId": 1,
                    "language": "en"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Qué",
                    "WhatPageId": 1,
                    "language": "es"
                },
            ],
            "WhatPageImages": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "image title 1",
                    "WhatPageId": 1,
                    "WhatPageImagesTranslations": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "title": "What",
                            "WhatPageImageId": 1,
                            "language": "en"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "title": "Qué",
                            "WhatPageImageId": 1,
                            "language": "es"
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I can use this function that check if its an array or an object, and transform the data recursively:

```
export const transformTranslatedData = function(data) {
    var clonedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    const transform = function(data) {
        for (var prop in data) {
            if (data[prop].length > 0 && data[prop] instanceof Array && data[prop][0].hasOwnProperty('language')) {
                var transformedData = data[prop].reduce(function(prev, current, index) {
                    prev[current.language] = current;

                    return prev;
                }, {});
                data[prop] = transformedData;

            } else if (data[prop] instanceof Object && !(data[prop] instanceof Array)) {
                transformTranslatedData(data[prop]);
            } else if (data[prop] instanceof Array) {
                let array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[prop]));
                array.forEach((item) => {
                    transformTranslatedData(item);
                });
            }
        }

        return data;
    };
    if (clonedData instanceof Array) {
        var newData = [];
        clonedData.map((item) => {
            newData.push(transform(item));
        });
    } else if (clonedData instanceof Object && !(clonedData instanceof Array)) {
        var newData = {};

        newData = transform(clonedData);
    }

    return newData;
};
```

This works, but only for the first level of the object —`WhatPageTranslations`—. On the second level, when it reaches `WhatPageImagesTranslations`, it transforms the data, but this data is not appended to the object.

If anyone has any idea why is this happening I would be grateful!

Comment: `transformTranslatedData` makes a copy of the object before modifying it. So when you recurse, it's modifying a copy, not the original object, and you never put the result into the current object.

Comment: Its true that `transformTranslatedData` stringify and parses `data` at the beginning, this creating a copy; but this `clonedData` is what we are processing in `transform`, and what we are returning. Why is not added to `clonedData`?

Comment: `transform` calls `transformTranslatedData` again. That makes *another* copy of the nested object, and transforms that.

Comment: Of course… I should be calling `transform` in both `else if (data[prop]...`. But same result anyway, `WhatPageImagesTranslations ` is not being modified.

Comment: Ok, with this modification the function worked as expected. Tons of thanks…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `transformTranslatedData` recursively, it makes a copy of the object that you pass it, and modifies that. So the object you're recursing through doesn't get modifies.

YOU need to copy the result of the transform back into the original object.

```
        } else if (data[prop] instanceof Object && !(data[prop] instanceof Array)) {
            data[prop] = transformTranslatedData(data[prop]);
        } else if (data[prop] instanceof Array) {
            let array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[prop]));
            data[prop] = array.map((item) => {
                transformTranslatedData(item);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Ok, is working. But the way I wrote this function looks dirty to me… Do you have any recommendation to make it cleaner?

Comment: It seems OK to me. You could simplify it and improve performance by not cloning the object in the first place. Let the caller clone their object before calling this.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it… Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you *can* simplify your recursive function. In your solution, you seem to be cloning a lot (at each recursive call). You can create a deep copy once and then be free to modify it in your recursive function (as @Barmar mentioned).

This considerably focuses our effort to examining and deciding whether or not to transform the "current" part of the data in the recursion:

```js
const myData = {
  "WhatPage": [{
    "id": 1,
    "WhatPageTranslations": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "What",
        "WhatPageId": 1,
        "language": "en"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Qué",
        "WhatPageId": 1,
        "language": "es"
      },
    ],
    "WhatPageImages": [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "image title 1",
      "WhatPageId": 1,
      "WhatPageImagesTranslations": [{
          "id": 1,
          "title": "What",
          "WhatPageImageId": 1,
          "language": "en"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Qué",
          "WhatPageImageId": 1,
          "language": "es"
        },
      ]
    }, ]
  }]
};


function transform(data) {
  // base case
  if (data instanceof Array && data.length && data[0].hasOwnProperty('language')) {
    return data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[curr.language] = curr;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }

  // array but not base case
  if (data instanceof Array) return data.map(transform);

  // object but not base case
  if (typeof data === 'object' && !(data instanceof Array)) {
    for (let key in data) {
      data[key] = transform(data[key]);
    }
  }

  // primitive, so return as is
  return data;
}

console.log(transform(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myData))));
```